# Check if a word is before another

Tags: c#, strings, unit-testing

Let's consider a method like this:

```
public bool IsWordABeforeWordB(string Text, string WordA, string WordB)
{
   ...
}
```

By `Word` I mean a string composed of more than one character.

Test cases:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IsWordABeforeWordB_ShouldBeTrue()
{
    string Text = "CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDTest] ASC)";
    bool result = AtomicCheckMethods.IsWordABeforeWordB(Text, "CLUSTERED", "ASC");
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}

[TestMethod]
public void IsWordABeforeWordB_ShouldBeFalse()
{
    string Text = "CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDTest] ASC)";
    bool result = AtomicCheckMethods.IsWordABeforeWordB(Text, "PRIMARY KEY", "CONSTRAINT");
    result.Should().BeFalse();
}

[TestMethod]
public void IsWordABeforeWordB_IgnoreCase_ShouldBeTrue()
{
    string Text = "CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDTest] ASC)";
    bool result = AtomicCheckMethods.IsWordABeforeWordB(Text, "clustered", "asc");
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}

[TestMethod]
public void IsWordABeforeWordB_IgnoreCase_ShouldBeFalse()
{
    string Text = "CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDTest] ASC)";
    bool result = AtomicCheckMethods.IsWordABeforeWordB(Text, "primary key", "constraint");
    result.Should().BeFalse();
}
```

What I tried:

```
public static bool IsWordABeforeWordB(string Text, string WordA, string WordB)
{
    string stringBeforeWordB = Text.Substring(0, Text.IndexOf(WordB, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    return stringBeforeWordB.IndexOf(WordA, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

Can I do it better?

Comment: You can do better by more carefully specifying the problem you're trying to solve. Your program actually solves the problem "is WordA a substring of Text that ends before the first occurrence of known substring WordB?"  It does not solve the problem "Does there exist any substring of Text equal to WordA that occurs and ends before any substring of Text equal to WordB?", which is how I would have interpreted the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code is actually unit test code, so lets review that part before the review of your main function:

- *Consider switching to [NUnit](http://nunit.org/)* – Based on the `[TestMethod]` I'm assuming you are using MS Test, but this is somewhat limited, so consider switching to a test tool with better options.
- *Test more than the 'happy flow'* – In one company I've worked some of the test were categorised as being in the 'happy flow', indicating the normal use cases where everyone is happy. However, you should test for more cases than these happy cases. Here are some cases you haven't tested for:

  - One or both texts are null (or empty)
  - Texts are substrings of each other
  - Text occurs multiple places in the text to be searched
- *Let test method allow multiple cases* – If you switch to NUnit, it is easy to extend the test method to allow for multiple case. And in your case you actually only do one test, with various input, which is a typical case for multiple test cases. Here is an untested example using [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.4):

  ```
  static object[] TextBeforeTextCases =
  {
      // expectedResult, firstText, secondText
      new object[] { true, "CLUSTERED", "ASC" },
      new object[] { false, "PRIMARY KEY", "CONSTRAINT" },
      new object[] { true, "clustered", "asc" },
      new object[] { false, "primary key", "constraint" }
  }

  static string baseText = 
      "CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDTest] ASC)";

  [Test, TestCaseSource("TextBeforeTextCases")]
  public void IsTextBeforeTextTest(bool expectedResult, 
                                   string firstText, 
                                   secondText)
  {
      AtomicCheckMethods
          .IsWordABeforeWordB(baseText, firstText, secondText)
          .Should().Be(expectedResult);
  }
  ```

  This would allow for very easy extension with multiple test cases as indicated in previous point, and it also adheres to the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). Here is one version with some extended tests:

  ```
  static object[] TextBeforeTextCases =
  {
      // expectedResult, firstText, secondText
      new object[] { true, "CLUSTERED", "ASC" },
      new object[] { false, "PRIMARY KEY", "CONSTRAINT" },
      new object[] { true, "constraint", "st" }, // Legal due to "clustered"
      new object[] { false, "primary key", "key" },
      new object[] { true, "primary", "" },
      new object[] { true, "", "key" },

      new object[] { false, null, "asc" },
      new object[] { false, "primary key", null },

  }
  ```

And here are some notes on your main function:

- *Using regex's would most likely slow down performance* – Compiling a regex expression, matching against them and then doing index comparisons would most likely be slower than your current solution and my suggested solution below
- *Test for more rand cases* – Your code is in the "happy flow" state assuming that the user always present good strings, and no null values, and so on. Please do handle more rand cases, like null values or empty strings
- *Possibly change naming* – You've gotten some comments on what is a word, and I would also like to add that `wordA` and `wordB` are not good names, neither for variables or within function name. My suggestions, albeit not optimal, is to use `firstText`, `secondText` and the function name of `IsTextBeforeText()`. I would also add a comment indicating what happens in the various cases.
- *Avoid temporary strings* – In general having extra strings has a slight cost associated with it, so I would rather just use the indices for verification and comparisons.

All in all this ends with the following function:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if firstText is occuring before secondText in baseText.
    /// Texts can't be substrings of each other. Empty strings matches
    /// most places, and if any text is null the result is false.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsTextBeforeText(string baseText, string firstText, string secondText)
    {
        if (baseText == null || firstText == null || secondText == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var firstIndexOfFirstText = baseText.IndexOf(firstText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var lastIndexOfSecondText = baseText.LastIndexOf(secondText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        // Only return true if both texts are found (idx != -1 ) and the ending position of
        // firstText is before start position of secondText
        return firstIndexOfFirstText != -1 && lastIndexOfSecondText != -1 &&
               firstIndexOfFirstText + firstText.Length < lastIndexOfSecondText;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're naming your parameters incorrectly. The [naming guidelines for parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229004(v=vs.100).aspx) specify camel casing.

Your method declaration should look like this:

```
public static bool IsWordABeforeWordB(string text, string wordA, string wordB)
```

---

Your current implementation also has a bug. You are assuming that the source text contains `wordB` - if it doesn't you'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` on the substring.

---

I'd suggest that performance probably doesn't matter here so you may as well just do it the long way:

```
public static bool IsWordABeforeWordB(string text, string wordA, string wordB)
{
    // Omitted checking text, wordA and wordB for null.
    var indexOfFirstWordA = text.IndexOf(wordA, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (indexOfFirstWordA == -1)
    {
         // throw exception or return false.
    }
    var indexOfLastWordB = text.LastIndexOf(wordB, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (indexOfLastWordB == -1)
    {
        // throw exception or return false.
    }

    // edited based on holroy's comment.
    // Otherwise we'd be wrong if wordB was a substring of wordA
    // e.g. wordA: hello, wordB: lo 
    return indexOfFirstWordA + wordA.Length < indexOfLastWordB;

}
```

I've assumed that `IsWordABeforeWordB("Sample text is sample", "text", "sample")` should return true as "text" does appear before one of the "sample"s. If that's not the behaviour you were going for you can change the `LastIndexOf` to a simple `IndexOf`

---

The definition of a "word" is a bit loose here. You could do a Regular Expression match to get the indexes which would allow you to use the "\b" word anchor. I've just assumed (as your OP) that it's simply a sequence of characters.

Comment: Thanks, could you please also provide a version with Regular Expression?

Comment: @FrancescoB. - I don't have time at the moment but something like this:  `var match = Regex.Match(text, "\\b" + wordA + "\\b");` then use `match.Success` and `match.Index`.